# Parenthetical numbers in Git documentation

Tags: git, unix

What do the parenthetical numbers in the [Kernel.org Git docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) reference?

For example: `git(1) Manual Page`   `git-add(1)`   `git-am(1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers refer to [sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) of the Unix manual.
That notation is not specific to git, it's common in all [man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) on Unix.

Comment: For an example of when this matters, see [`man 3 mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp) versus [`man 1 mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp).

Comment: Heh, mktemp?  Why not the manpage collision for all time: `man printf`, of course, returns the documentation for the obscure and forgotten /usr/bin/printf utility for formatting output in shell scripts.  If you want to remember the precision specifiers for `printf()` you need to know that it's in section 3.

Comment: @AndyRoss: Yes, that can be a problem -- but the `printf` utility is (I hope) neither obscure nor forgotten. (It's also built into some shells, including bash.)